# Executing Twig statements from within a MatchMedia JS function?

Tags: javascript, twig, media-queries, matchmedia

Is it possible to execute Twig 'include' statements from within a Javascript MatchMedia Query?

Am trying to get round another issue by simply rendering a different menu type at our tablet breakpoint.

I know the JS can't talk to the server but is it possible to execute a twig command in this way at all?

```
         if (matchMedia) {
         const mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 992px)");

         mq.addListener(WidthChange);
         WidthChange(mq);
         }

         // media query change
         function WidthChange(mq) {
         if (mq.matches) {
         // window width is greater than 992px
```

{% include 'snippets/navbar.rain' with {'type': 'Desktop'} %}

```
         } else {

         // window width is less than 992px
```

{% include 'snippets/navbar.rain' with {'type': 'Tablet'} %}

```
         }

       }
```

I can't find the correct syntax anywhere online or even examples of whether this is actually a possible solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

twig is a templating language executed on the server. So the answer is no. The `include` statement are to be run on the server when rendering the html. The js will run in the browser when a DOM has been created.

Comment: Thanks, suspected as much although thought there may be a work around.

Comment: This answer is partially incorrect. If OP would place his javascript directly inside a twig template, it would work (as long as `navbar.rain` produces correct javascript)

Comment: It is impossible to make a js callback responding to a match media query interact with the rendering of a twig template which happens on the server (whereas the JS and match media stuff happen on the client). What OP could do, depending on what those templates render, if it's pure html is to store those into some hidden div and then display them according to the media query (then css may be enough). If there is JS in those it might be harder, but this is not the original question.

Comment: That is exactly what OP is doing. He is not relying on an actual javascript variable to create the output. Both `navbar.rain` with type `desktop` and type `table` WILL be included in the source code.

Comment: Yeah that's correct, both 'types' will be included in a Twig navbar snippet so they are both loading on the page either way. Ended up using your solution adz5a although was hoping to avoid having to render both the menus twice. This could of course also be achieved with simple CSS